# How to find 'task runner templates' in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sorry if I am missing the obvious, but in the help page for Visual Studio Code tasks here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks the text says:

> Select the Tasks: Configure Task Runner command and you will see a list of task runner templates. Select Others to create a task which runs an external command.

I don't see 'Others', I just see the following in tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "c:/Windows/sysnative/bash.exe",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-c 'cd /mnt/c/SVNProj/Leda/trunk/software/Source/LedaAP_win_linux; make'"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

How do I get to see the task templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is bad behavior on vscode's part but I can only get the options presented after clicking on "Configure task runner" if there is **NO** tasks.json file.  So if you already have a tasks.json file, rename it and try again.  Then the templates will appear.